# Alterar a cor do indicador da aba no Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Já tentei de diversas formas trocar a cor do que eles chamam de "tab indicator", mas sem sucesso... Mesmo utilizando o "Android Action Bar Style Generator" a cor desse indicador permanece azul claro.

[teste http://nsae01.casimages.net/img/2014/09/11/140911033853988172.png](http://nsae01.casimages.net/img/2014/09/11/140911033853988172.png)

Estou utilizando versões 3.0+ (com AppCompat). Meu XML está exatamente como o gerador me passou...

[Layout gerado](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=David&compat=appcompat&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=1&neutralPressed=0&backColor=f45619%2C100&secondaryColor=fff%2C100&tabColor=f45619%2C100&tertiaryColor=fff%2C100&accentColor=f80%2C100&cabBackColor=ff4d00%2C100&cabHighlightColor=ff4d00%2C100)

Comment: Se as configurações que usou são as mesmas que eu vi quando abri (não houve perda), faltou você especificar o `Style compatibility` como `AppCompat`. O atual esta como `Holo`, o que ignora algumas configurações específicas de estilo do `AppCompat`.

Comment: Na verdade eu coloquei como AppCompat, o link que não deve ter carregado essa opção :/
Fui verificar os XMLs e todos possuem essa compatibilidade...

Comment: Ok, ele perdeu a informação, desculpe. Aliás... Como está fazendo essas abas? Usando o `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`? Ou está usando outra biblioteca?

Comment: Estou utilizando fragments: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost e as abas com TabWidget. Consegui alterar o background das abas, mas o indicador eu não consegui alterar de maneira alguma :'(

Comment: Tente fazer o seguinte, não consigo testar mas acho que vai dar certo (se der eu posto como resposta). Itere sobre os filhos do `TabWidget` (usando `getChildAt(...)` e `getChildCount`) e use o `setBackgroundResource` como o `drawable` `tab_indicator_ab` gerado pelo `Style Generator`). Isso depois de ter configurado todas as `Tabs`.

Comment: Desculpe, sou extremamente novato em Android, como eu faria para iterar sobre as TabWidgets?
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("A"), Teste1.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("B"), Teste2.class, null);

A "mTabHost" é um FragmentTabHost, tem um método chamado getTabWidget, ele retorna todas as TabWidgets ou só a última?

Comment: Vou montar uma resposta exemplificando como deve ser feito.

Comment: Muito obrigado, muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `FragmentTabHost` retorna o `TabWidget` (apenas um), que é a `View` responsável por desenhar essas abas. Cada filho dele é uma aba diferente.

A configuração de cor do `Tab` do `Style Generator` se aplica apenas ao `Tab` do `ActionBar`.

No seu caso esta usando o `TabHost` e o `TabWidget`, e esse estilo não se aplica a eles, infelizmente.

Para customizar a aba, precisa recuperar o `TabWidget` e estilizar cada filho. Dessa forma:

```
// Assim como voce mencionou
TabWidget tabWidget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();

// Como o TabWidget eh um ViewGroup, ele tem filhos e podemos iterar
// sobre os mesmos
int childCount = tabWidget.getChildCount();

for(int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
    View child = tabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(i);
    // Que eh o mesmo que
    //View child = tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
    // Vide o codigo fonte

    // O Drawable vai variar conforme o nome do seu tema, confirme se tem
    // algum nome parecido com esse e altere aqui
    child.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator_ab);
}
```

Use esse código ao final da configuração do `TabHost`.

O arquivo `tab_indicator_ab.xml` que esta no diretório `/res/drawable` é bem parecido com esse:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_ab" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_ab" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_ab" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_ab" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_ab" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_ab" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_ab" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Novamente muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente... Não querendo abusar mas me surgiu uma dúvida: Você recomenda o uso do Tab da ActionBar ou o TabHost e o TabWidget?

Comment: O Tab do ActionBar é muito simples, é só um Tab que tem um `ActionBar.TabListener` vinculado. Ele não tem vínculo com o conteúdo da Aba, isso significa que você tem que gerenciar isso (seja com `FragmentManager` ou de outra forma). É bastante usado em conjunto com o `ViewPager`, um atualiza o outro. No `TabHost` ele obriga a você a fornecer o conteúdo (`Fragment` ou `View`), sendo assim ele é mais rígido, porém é mais simples. Acho que vai depender do caso de uso, sincronizar o `ActionBar Tab` com o `ViewPager` é bem mais chatinho mas funciona.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado. Você me ajudou muito mesmo, isso me travou por 2 dias... Obrigado!